# Pass Laravel Image Object To External API with CURL?

Tags: php, api, curl, file-upload, laravel

At the moment I have an API which is working along with a dummy test site:

Dummy Site = http://www.example.com
API = http://api.myapi.com

At the moment the API works though I'm unable to get the ajax image upload to work. Here is how my API is working in this instance:

1. Send the AJAX request to http://www.example.com/data/image_handler
2. Check validation and access in the http://www.example.com/data/image_handler
3. Send CURL request with all the `$input` to http://api.myapi.com/data/image_handler
4. http://api.myapi.com/data/image_handler passes data to `MediaFile::createMediaFile`

The step which is failing is where I'm sending data from the http://www.example.com/data/image_handler > http://api.myapi.com/data/image_handler. I'm trying to send the Input::file() as an object.

JS AJAX request - works fine:

```
    var data = new FormData();
    if ($this.parents('.media-data') && $this.parents('.media-data').data('media') > 0) {
        data.append('mediaId', $this.parents('.media-data').data('media'));
    }
    data.append('file', input);
    data.append('mediaLink', 'media_link');
    data.append('objectId', 1);
    data.append('objectType', 1);
    data.append('usageType', 1);
    data.append('mediaType', 1);

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '/data/image_handler',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            response = data;
            return response;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            response = data;
            return response;
        }
    });
```

http://www.example.com/data/image_handler

```
public function imageHandler(){

    try{

        $input = Input::all();

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($input); die();

        $input['class'] = 'MediaFile';          

        if( isset($input['mediaId']) && $input['mediaId'] && $input['mediaId'] != 0 ){
            $input['function'] = 'updateMediaFile';
        }else{
            $input['function'] = 'createMediaFile';
        }

        $class = $input['class'];
        $function = $input['function'];

        if( count(Config::get('ajax.'.$input['class'].'.'.$input['function'].'.validation_rules')) ) {
            $validator = Validator::make($input, Config::get('ajax.'.$input['class'].'.'.$input['function'].'.validation_rules'));
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $data = array(
                        'response' => 'failed',
                        'data' => array(
                            'error_messages' => array(
                                $validator->errors()->toArray(),
                                ),
                            ),
                         );
                return Response::json($data);
            }
        }

        $token = new Token();
        $token->token = str_random(32);
        $token->save();

        $input['token'] = $token->token;
        $input['site_id'] = Config::get('api_setup.site_id');
        $input['application_id'] = Config::get('api_setup.application_id');
        $input['key'] = Config::get('api_setup.key');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, Config::get('api_setup.api_image_url').http_build_query($input) );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data); die();

        if(is_object($data)) {
            $data = array(
                'response' => 'success',
                'data' => $data->toArray(),
            );

        } else {
            $data = array(
                    'response' => 'failed',
                    'data' => array(
                        'error_messages' => array(
                                'here' => 'here',
                                'something_went_wrong' => Lang::get('ajax.errors.wrong_file_format'),
                            ),
                        ),
                     );

        }

    return Response::json($data);

    } catch( Exception $e) {

        return $e->getMessage();

        $data = array(
                'response' => 'failed',
                'data' => array(
                    'error_messages' => array(
                            'or_here' => 'or_here',
                            'something_went_wrong' => Lang::get('ajax.errors.something_went_wrong'),
                        ),
                    ),
                 );

        return Response::json($data);
    }
}
```

http://api.myapi.com/data/image_handler

```
public function imageHandler(){

    try{
        $input = Input::all();

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($input); die();

        $class = $input['class'];
        $function = $input['function'];

        $functionParams = array();
        $reference = new ReflectionMethod($class, $function);

        foreach( $reference->getParameters() as $param) {
            if( isset($input[$param->name]) ) {
                $functionParams[$param->name] = $input[$param->name];                       
            } else {
                $functionParams[$param->name] = Config::get('ajax.'.$class.'.'.$function.'.function_parameters_defaults.'.$param->name);
            }
        }

        // $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod($class, $function);
        $data = $reference->invokeArgs(new $class(), $functionParams);

        if(is_object($data)) {
            $data = array(
                'response' => 'success',
                'data' => $data->toArray(),
            );
        } else {
            $data = array(
                    'response' => 'failed',
                    'data' => array(
                        'error_messages' => array(
                                'something_went_wrong' => Lang::get('ajax.errors.wrong_file_format'),
                            ),
                        ),
                     );

        }

    return Response::json($data);

    } catch( Exception $e) {

        return $e->getMessage();

        $data = array(
                'response' => 'failed',
                'data' => array(
                    'error_messages' => array(
                            'something_went_wrong' => Lang::get('ajax.errors.something_went_wrong'),
                        ),
                    ),
                 );

        return Response::json($data);
    }
}
```

Here is what the response looks like when I print_r($input) at the first controller - http://www.example.com/data/image_handler:

```
Array
    (
        [mediaLink] => media_link
        [objectId] => 1
        [objectType] => 1
        [usageType] => 1
        [mediaType] => 1
        [file] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
            (
                [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
                [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => italian-guido-gangsta-italian-guido-italy-gangsta-1291824813.jpg
                [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
                [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 74294
                [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
                [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpDXmwcc
                [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpDXmwcc
            )

    )
```

Here is what the response looks like when I print_r($input) at the second controller - http://api.myapi.com/data/image_handler - here you can see that `$input['file']` doesn't exist here because it is an object I believe.

```
    Array
    (
        [mediaLink] => media_link
        [objectId] => 1
        [objectType] => 1
        [usageType] => 1
        [mediaType] => 1
        [class] => MediaFile
        [function] => createMediaFile
        [token] => fIXI0cV4la4HwiXmtevhoXnG8QkOTX9S
        [site_id] => 2
        [application_id] => yAzK0HFDAuWJSpA70S8R
        [key] => 25quv4ImMjHkMH3ESqzf
    )
```

Comment: So which one in working example? because I getting same problem while sending `Input:file('image')` in cURL request, so should I try your `http://api.myapi.com/data/image_handler`, is it working for you?